# Tenant Log Level with Logback

Tags: java, spring, logback, multi-tenant

In a multi-tenant system we are currently using `MDC` to identify tenant specific logs and such. Now we got to a point where we would like to specify log levels based on the tenant in context.

The idea is basically to turn on `DEBUG` level for a specific tenant whenever we need. As the system uses a huge base of tenants, it is not an option solely to turn on `DEBUG` level.

The first though was to set the level to `DEBUG` but attaching to it a `Filter` that will allow logging only the tenants we wish to log, and maybe using JMX we could enable and disable them.

Is there a better way to solve this problem or something already implemented for this use-case?

Comment: Did you find the answer ?

Comment: Not really. But we implemented the solution for this using the tenant on logger name. That way we could set the level by class and if required by class/tenant.

Comment: Can you please share some details, or have some example in git repo ?